# How do I save multiple images from my Dropbox app to my Camera Roll

Tags: ios, dropbox, camera-roll

I need to save multiple photos from my Dropbox to my camera roll. From what I can see you can only do one at a time. Is there a way to this by folder? I have 60+ images and and doing one at a time will be tedious and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the Carousel app? They're about to discontinue it in March, but it should still be available. From what I recall, you should be able to select multiple images in that app, and you might be able to save them to your Camera Roll from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I wanted to transfer multiple photos from my dropbox to my iPhone SE 2020. I didn't find a solution (December 2021), so here's my suggestion [it's kinda slow but you don't have to download one by one]

What I've done is:

1. Open **Safari**.
2. Navigate to [dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/)
3. **DO NOT ENTER THE APP**, continue with logging in to your profile on the website.
4. Go to the folder with your photos or to all files. Click on the checkbox above all files. Then click the three dots, **Download**. This will download a zip file to the **Files** app on your iOS device.
5. When it's done, open the **Files** app. Go to **Downloads** or **Recents** and click on the icon of the zip file you just downloaded. [if you downloaded all the files from folder "FAMILY", the file should probably be named FAMILY.zip]. This will create a folder [for example "FAMILY"] in the **Downloads** or **Recents** in the **Files** app which contains all of the photos you want to download.
6. Now open the folder and, in the top-right corner click the three dots > select and click the **Select All** in the top-left corner.
7. After you have selected all of the photos, click the box with the arrow in the bottom-left corner and click save images.
   Now you have all your images in the **Recents** folder in your photos app.

My software is iOS 14.7.1
I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For iPad or iPhone users, get free app called Documents.
Takes a little bit to work out but will do what you want.

Please note, this will take photos from your Dropbox and place them back on your camera roll. They will no longer appear in Dropbox.

Download “Documents” from App Store (free).
Open app, look to L/H side for “+Add”, make sure you can see YOUR Dropbox.
Click on Dropbox and sign in.
Once signed in find the file you want to go to your camera roll.
HINT: Do not delete any photos or files in here because to do so will also delete them from Dropbox.
Top R/H corner click on “sync”.
Click on folder to open.
Click on “Select” then select photos you want to go to camera roll or click on “Select All”.
L/H column click on “Move”.
Pop up press “Photos” then “above Photos”.
Photos will go to your camera roll.
This is not hard to use once you get used to it and is the only app I could find to bulk move photos from Dropbox. 
Otherwise you do it one by one.

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed instructions on how this app can be used to solve the problem?